# loop over json in SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am receiving some JSON from an end point, but I'm having issues when I try and loop through the data and pass to a SwiftyJSON object

the json :

```
   {  
       findItemsByKeywordsResponse:[  
           {                  
               searchResult:[  
                   {  
                       item:[  
                           {  
                            itemId:[  
                                "232053825102"
                            ]
                        },
                        {  
                            itemId:[  
                                "232053825102"
                            ]
                        }
                   }
              ]
          } 
      ]
}
```

Im trying to loop through the itemId's

Some sauce:

```
if let data = response.data  {
    if let jsonData:JSON? = JSON(data: data){
        if let findItems = jsonData["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"].array {//This line works
            if let searchResult //HERES THE ERROR, HOW TO LOOP findItems?????  
        }
    }                                  
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to access each `itemId` string

```
guard let data = response.data else { return }
let json = JSON(data:data)
guard let jsonElms = json["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"].array?.first?["searchResult"].array?.first?["item"].array else { return }

for elm in jsonElms {
    let itemID = elm["itemId"].array?.first?.string
}
```

Comment: cheers @appzTourLife...works...will vote when I have enough reps :)